# Is there a CTL* formula that translates into mu-calculus formula Y.νZ.(...) with alternation depths 2,1 for Y,Z?

Tags: computation-tree-logic, mu-calculus

A CTL* formula `EFG p` is equivalent to mu-calculus formula `Y.(<>Y | νZ.(<>Z & p))`. In this formula, the alternation depths are `ad(Y)=ad(Z)=1`.
Is there a CTL* formula that translates into `YνZ(...)` with alternation depths 2,1 for Y,Z?

And a similar question:
Is there a CTL* formula that translates into `νXYνZ(...)` with alternation depths 3,2,1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: `Y.νZ.[](Y | pZ)`, which corresponds to CTL formula `AFAG p`.

**Long answer to 1st question**
For this answer I use the def of alternation depth taken from Handbook on Model Checking, Chapter 26.
For instance, the formula `Y.(<>Y | νZ.(<>(Zp)))` has alternation depths  ad(Y)=ad(Z)=1, so the AD of the formula is 1 as well. Note that this formula can also be written as `Y.νZ.<>(Y | Zp)` which has AD of 2. So the original question asks about the *minimal* possible depth.
Now consider a slightly different formula `Y.νZ.[](Y | Zp)` of AD=2. In contrast to the formula with `<>` operator, this formula cannot be rewritten into a formula of depth 1 (I believe so). Finally, this formula corresponds to the CTL* formula `AXFG p`. This answers the original question.

Remark. I mistakenly thought that `Y.νZ.[](Y | pZ)` could be rewritten into a formula of AD=1 just like for `<>`, which prompted the question.

**Answer to 2nd question**
`νX.Y.νZ.[](sZ | Y | Xn)`, which corresponds to CTL* formula `AX(GF!n -> GFs)`.